# apt-get with unstable connection?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm now on vacation for a month and my Internet connection is extremly unstable. I can't install any app, even with `--fix-missing`

Is there an option to continue downloading after a "break" ?

Thank you for helping and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

This question ist quite old and this answer is likely to come late to help during your vacation, still it deserves an answer as you might travel again (and it shows up on google).

I'd suggest to use [mosh](https://mosh.org/) which is specifically designed for unstable connections, it even survives changing IP addresses. Just install it on your client and server (e.g. `apt install mosh`) and you are good to go `mosh your.server.com`.

Alternatively, or in addition, I'd suggest to look at [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) which allows you to open a session that is kept open with all output and all running processes on connection loss (and on explicit disconnect of course). This allows you to reconnect and continue from where you have been or where the running processes has taken you while being disconnected.

Just install it on your server (e.g. `apt install tmux`) and open a new session with `tmux`. On connection loss, reconnect to your server, list open sessions with `tmux ls` and connect to the desired one using `tmux attach -d -t <session id from tmux ls>`.

tmux is extremly feature rich, see the man page or google for all the glory bells and whistles.